# Split a string in SSRS if there is a space in between words

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, expression, business-intelligence

I have a field with multiple words in it. I want to separate the words onto different lines rather than have them separated by spaces.

So for example “Not Great”, I want to put “Not” on 1st line and “Great” on 2nd line, like so:

```
Not
Great
```

There could be words with “/” character in between i.e. “Great / Good” where I want to put everything after 1st word in 2nd line and everything after “/” in 3rd line i.e.

```
Great 
/
Good
```

Basically, whenever there is space, I want split that string into multiple lines. How do I do that in SSRS?

Comment: Could you edit and improve the question? A spell check, some more [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make the examples readable (it's a bit of a "wall of text" at the moment), and most importantly some info on what you've tried so far would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you want the string broken up into different lines.
Do you mean on separate lines within the same tablix cell?

Thats straightfoward see
http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/reporting-services-add-line-break-between-words-custom-code.aspx

If you mean to split the string so the words are on different Tablix cells one approach would be to use a sub report on a list.

Set the list data set to the original data set containing the multiple word string, pass the string to the sub report as a parameter. 
On the sub report pass the parameter to a data set that splits the string into individual lines.
Losts of suggestions for how to do that here
[Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the space with a carriage return and line feed:

```
=Replace(Fields!SomeWords.Value, " ", vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 1):

=Fields!SomeFields.Value.Replace(Space(1), vbCrLf)